# Show that $S$ is a bounded subset of $X$ if it converges to $p$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, solution-verification

I have been trying to solve this problem using a definition of bounded sets. I found different results online but they don't use this definition to prove it. I would like to know if it can be proven like this:

**Definition:**

Let $A$ be a subset of a metric space $(X,d)$. We say $A$ is bounded if $A \subseteq B(x, r)$ for some $r > 0$ and some $x\in X$.

**Question**

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in a metric space $(X,d)$ which converges to $p$. Put $S = \{x_n|n \in \mathbb{N} \}$

Show that $S$ is a bounded subset of $X$

**My Attempt**

As $x_n \rightarrow p$, thus there exists a natural number $N$  s.t $d(x_n,p) < 1 $ for$\ n\geq N$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Thus $d(x_N,p) < 1$

Let $K = max\{d(x_i,x_N)| 1\leq i <N \}$

Thus $d(x_n,p)\leq d(x_N,p) +d(x_N,x_n)$

$ \ \ \ \ \leq d(x_N,p) +K$

$ \ \ \ \ <1 +K$

Now let $r = 1 +K$

Thus $S \subseteq B(p,r)$

**This concludes my attempt**

Comment: Your attempt is correct.

Comment: Note: you don’t have to choose least possible $r$. So $r= \max (K \cup \{1\})$ works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your choice of $r$ is not correct.** Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric as a metric space. let $S=\{1000,1005, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{4}, \ldots, \frac{1}{n}, \ldots\}$ be a sequence converging to the $0$. Now,
For $n \geq 3$, we have $d(x_n, 0) \leq 1$, In this case we get $K= 5= d(1000, 1005)$ and $r=1+K=6$. Since $1000, 1005 \notin B(0, 6)$, $S$ is not a subset of $B(0,6)$.

**For correct choice of $r$** :
In your proof Choose $K= \max \{d(p, x_i)\:|\: 1 \leq i \leq N\}$ then you can take $r=K+1$.